# Mapping on slices of a List

Tags: scala

I was wondering what the best way to accomplish the following given a `List`:

`val l = List("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m" /*...,x,y,z*/)`

For each 5 items (or less for the last segment) apply a function like:

`...map(_.mkString(","))`

Such that I end up with a `List` that looks like:

`List("a,b,c,d,e","f,g,h,i,j","k,l,m,n,o",/*...,*/"u,v,w,x,y,"z")`

Perhaps there is a common term for this type of list processing, however I'm not aware of it. Essentially I'm grouping items, so using `zipWithIndex` and then modding by 5 on the index to indicate where to partition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `grouped(n)` method on the List.

```
val l = List("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m")
l.grouped(5).map(_.mkString(",")).toList
```

Results in

```
List("a,b,c,d,e", "f,g,h,i,j", "k,l,m"): List[String]
```

Comment: Wow big'ol RTFM fail badge awarded to me!

Comment: P.S. my REPL spits out the result looking like:
`res11: List[String] = List(a,b,c,d,e, f,g,h,i,j, k,l,m)`

How do I get the individual elements to be wrapped in quotes like your result above? To me, the way the REPL displays it is a bit confusing since I'm using commas in mkString and it uses commas to separate elements in lists.

Comment: @ThaDon Ammonite would print to the REPL in a less ambiguous way, showing quotations around Strings by default.

Comment: @ThaDon I used scalakata.com for this. It's pretty awesome. http://www.scalakata.com/gist/bd9c5a2fb161ea09d6c9ae9d2146bee2

Comment: @stewSquared wow, I've been living under a rock. Ammonite looks pretty cool

Comment: @AlexBrand nice tool, could definitely see this coming in handy